# Installation and running mysql 5.6 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, service, ubuntu-14.04

I need to setup mysql5.6 server in ubuntu 14.04(32 bit). I downloaded **mysql-server_5.6.19-1ubuntu14.04_i386.deb-bundle.tar** from official site. I installed mysql using below commands:

```
dpkg -i mysql-5.6.16-debian6.0-x86_64.deb
```

for server, coummunuty etc which all comes in the tar file one by one. Steps I followed are mentioned in this site:
***http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-debian.html***

**I can see myconf.cnf file also.**

But when I executed the command to start mysql service it gave me error. Error: mysql service uynrecognized.

Kindly tell me what went wrong with my installation.

Thanks

Comment: I'm new to this platform, but as I understand, this is for questions related to coding only. You should ask your question in the Ubuntu community.

Comment: Not sure but as far as I understand, stackoverflow is a somehow wiki like platform in question / answer format for programmer questions, not for linux administration or other things. If you have questions about writing automation / installation shell scripts, you're at the right place here.

Comment: I suggest http://ubuntuforums.org/ for this question.

Comment: I asked on askubuntu. I will also post it on ubuntuforums.org.. Thanks